# convert assignment problem to The Maximum Flow Problem

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow, network-flow, hungarian-algorithm

According to the [article](https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/maximum-flow-linear-assignment-problem) I read in this link, the assignment problem can be turned into a maximum flow problem under certain conditions.
I know about the conversion of the minimum-cost flow problem, but I want to know from this method and under what conditions this problem becomes the maximum flow problem?

Comment: The Assignment Problem can *always* be turned into a Maximum Flow Problem. That is admittedly quite a complicated article, but it is very thorough on how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An assignment problem can be converted to a single maximum flow problem when all the allowed assignments have exactly the same weight.  The idea is to make a bipartite graph (plus global source and sink nodes) with a capacity 1 edge between each person and each allowed task for that person and see if you can find a flow with value equal to the number of people available.  If you can, then the flow represents the allocation of people to tasks.

The article explains how a more general assignment problem can also be converted to solving a series of maximum flow problems. (The assignment problem can be converted into a minimum-cost flow problem.  One method of solving a minimum-cost flow problem  is the Kuhn-Munkres Algorithm.  The Kuhn-Munkres Algorithm works by solving lots of maximum matching problems.  Each of these maximum matching problems can be converted into a maximum-flow problem.)